# Including separate javascript file in perl script

Tags: javascript, perl, refactoring

I have set of perl CGI webpages that I am attempting to do some refactoring on but have run into a wall.

Each of these scripts has some javascript and CSS currently written in the form:

```
my $JSCRIPT = << CODE;
function doStuff() {
  // Stuff
}
CODE;

my $CSS = <<BLOCK;
.css-stuff{}
BLOCK
```

The javascript and CSS is later loaded to the page using CGI

```
print $cgi->start_html( -script => [{-type => "javascript", -code => $JSCRIPT}],
                        -style => {-code => $CSS} );
```

Is there a good way to refactor this code so that instead of having copies of that $JSCRIPT in multiple files, I can have a single `common.js` or similar file? How do I include a file to accomplish this?

Comment: Worth noting that this usage of CGI is (soon to be) deprecated, and usage of a template engine such as Template Toolkit is recommended instead. See [CGI::Alternatives](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI%3A%3AAlternatives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `-code` use `-src` as shown in the CGI documentation.

```
print $q->start_html(-title=>'The Riddle of the Sphinx',
                     -script=>{-type=>'JAVASCRIPT',
                               -src=>'/javascript/sphinx.js'}
                     );

print $q->start_html(-title=>'The Riddle of the Sphinx',
                          -script=>[
                                    { -type => 'text/javascript',
                                      -src      => '/javascript/utilities10.js'
                                    },
                                    { -type => 'text/javascript',
                                      -src      => '/javascript/utilities11.js'
                                    },
                                    { -type => 'text/jscript',
                                      -src      => '/javascript/utilities12.js'
                                    },
                                    { -type => 'text/ecmascript',
                                      -src      => '/javascript/utilities219.js'
                                    }
                                 ]
                             );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following HTML to load a script from a file:

```
<script src="/path/to/file.js"></script>
```

Note that `/path/to/file.js` is relative to the document root of your webserver, and is not an absolute path on your filesystem.

As you may have noticed, embedding HTML/CSS/JavaScript in your Perl scripts is not very maintainable. I would recommend keeping your CSS and JavaScript in separate, static files and using a template library like [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) to generate your HTML. Using templates helps you separate your presentation logic from your business logic, and saves you from having to use `CGI.pm`'s arcane methods of generating complex HTML.

Here's an example using Template Toolkit to populate the path to your JavaScript file at runtime:

*foo.cgi*

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new or die Template->error;

my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header;

my $js_file = '/path/to/file.js';
$tt->process('foo.tt', { js_file => $js_file }) or die $tt->error;
```

*foo.tt*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello, Template Toolkit!</title>

    <script src="[% js_file %]"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, Template Toolkit!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Output*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello, Template Toolkit!</title>

    <script src="/path/to/file.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, Template Toolkit!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```